# Getting the base URL for a property via Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm working with the Google Analytics API, and am pulling a lot of data from it successfully.  The accounts feed (`https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/default`) returns a list of web properties connected to the account you're authorized for, in the following format (most actual values replaced, not sure how sensitive any of it is):

```
<entry gd:etag="W/&quot;<charsblahblahblah>.&quot;" gd:kind="analytics#account">
    <id>http://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/accounts/ga:########</id>
    <updated>2011-08-04T12:01:33.467-07:00</updated>
    <title>www.afifthofnothing.com</title>
    <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.google.com/analytics"/>
    <dxp:property name="ga:accountId" value="#####"/>
    <dxp:property name="ga:accountName" value="My Sites"/>
    <dxp:property name="ga:profileId" value="######"/>
    <dxp:property name="ga:webPropertyId" value="UA-#####-#"/>
    <dxp:property name="ga:currency" value="USD"/>
    <dxp:property name="ga:timezone" value="America/Los_Angeles"/>
    <dxp:tableId>ga:#######</dxp:tableId>
</entry>
```

I've previously been using the `<title>` element as the base URL for the property, which usually works because that's the default title that Google Analytics assigns to the property.  But if a user edits this (I'm querying my end-users' accounts, so I don't have control there) to something like "A Fifth Of Nothing", then the Analytics API will dutifully return that as the title, leaving me with no way to find the base URL.

I've scoured the [Analytics API documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/gdata/gdataReferenceAccountFeed.html) and googled around, searched SO, but don't see any way to get the base URL of a web property from Google Analytics.  I've tried querying the `id` field via the [OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php) for more info, and it just gives me more errors, saying the last part has to be `/default`.

Is there a way to get the base URL for a user's properties from the data API?  It seems like this would be something pretty basic.  If not, I'll have to resort to trying the title, and if it's not URL-like just have the user enter it themselves, which is not very user-friendly, but is the only thing I can come up with at this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strategy to use is to do a query against the ga:hostname dimension for ga:visits and sort descending.  You typically can use this to reveal the host/base url.

I don't think there is such a property for the "base url" because technically you can put the google tracking code on multiple websites.  And in this instance you would have multiple base url.

Comment: I'll look into the hostname dimension.  But on the settings page for each Profile (I have several profiles in my account, the above is just one entry) there is a "Website URL" field that I wish I could get at: http://i.imgur.com/jPMgb.png

Comment: I just checked it out, and I ended up querying for ga:hostname, with a metric of ga:visits, sorted by visits descending.  That way I can just pick the most common hostname, in case something goes weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
View Full Page URL In Reports
By default, the data in your reports includes only the Request URI and not the domain name:

URL of page: http://www.example.com/foldername/page.html
Request URI: /foldername/page.html
Domain name: www.example.com

If you'd like to see the domain name as well as the Request URI in your reports, create an Advanced filter for your view with the following settings:

Filter Type: Custom filter > Advanced
Field A: Hostname
Extract A: (.*)
Field B: Request URI
Extract B: (.*)
Output To: Request URI
Constructor: $A1$B1

Note that creating URL rewrite filters like the one described above can affect Analytics' ability to match your goals properly.

If you're using Analytics filters to rewrite your URLs, you need to make sure that your goal settings reflect these changes. Like all filters, URL-rewrite filters are applied to the raw data coming into your account, before goals are processed. As a result, your goal and funnel URLs should reflect the final, rewritten format of the URL. For example:

If your site's URL:

/directory/download/file.html

is rewritten by a filter to look like:

/download/file

then your goal should match

/download/file and not /directory/download/file.html
```